# update quantity Cart items using Sessions

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Hello I have a cart I want to update the quantity via session

Here are my failed attempts

I tried this, but same problem is that nothing changes but

```
<?php
foreach($_SESSION as $product)
{
                               
        ?> <form action='' method='POST'> <?php

        foreach($product as $key => $value)
        {  
            if($key == 0)
            {
                ?>   <input type='text' name='pro<?php echo $key ?>' value='<?php echo $value ?>'>  <?php
            }
            else if($key == 1)
            {
                 ?>    <input type='text' name='pro<?php echo $key ?>' value='<?php echo $value ?>'>    <?php
                 $prix = $value;
            }
            else if($key == 2)
            {
                ?>    <input type='text' name='pro<?php echo $key ?>' value='<?php echo $value ?>'>   <?php
                $quantity = $value;
            }    
         }                             
                                        
        ?>
        <?php echo $prix * $quantity ?> 
        <input type='submit' name='event' value='Update' >
        <input type='submit' name='event' value='Delete'>
        </form>
        <?php
                                        
}  
?>



<?php

    if(isset($_POST['event']))
    {
        $name = $_POST['pro0'];
        $price = $_POST['pro1'];
        $quantity = $_POST['pro2'];

        if($_POST['event'] == "Update")
        {
            $_SESSION[$name] = array($name,$price,$quantity);
            
            header('location:index.php?action=updated');
        }
        else if($_POST['event'] == "Delete")
        {
            unset($_SESSION[$name]);
            header('location:index.php?action=deleted');
        }
        
    }
?>
```

I tried this, but same problem is that nothing changes but
Please help me because this problem is bothering me

Comment: I see you make a get request with your `a` tag, but how do you expect to get values then into yout `POST` array? Your missing alot of code

Comment: Also never store all product details into a session. Like in your code the user can edit the price of the product by changing the posted price. You can better store a cart (Only the product id and quantity) into a database and store the cart ID into a session or cookie

Comment: Hi Baracuda078 , thank you to this comment , this means that the user will be able to hack the site by changing the price of the product, but ordinary users cannot do that.
But the question arises, how do I change the quantity of the product in the session?

Comment: At the moment im a bit busy, If I have time in the weekend I will take a look if I can  see a simple solution to your problem

Comment: if($_POST['action'] == "update")
 {
  foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $values)
  {
   if($_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$keys]['product_id'] == $_POST["product_id"])
   {
    $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$keys]['product_quantity'] = $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$keys]['product_quantity'] + $_POST["product_quantity"];
   }
  }
 
    }

Answer (score 0):

first, change this

```
if(   isset($_GET["action"]) == 'update' )
```

to

```
if(   isset($_GET["action"]) && $_GET["action"] == 'update' )
```

Comment: i changed it but same problem